# Autofill Google Form Text Item with the User's Email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm simply trying to autofill a question called Email in Google Form with the user's emails that they are logged in with. I cannot find a method that will set the value to the question when the Form loads.

```
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var form = FormApp.openById("formID");
var questions = form.getItems();


for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
  if (questions[i].title = "email").getType() == 'Email') 
    questions[i].?  = email
}
```